# Python cannot append when deriving from list

Tags: python

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm using py 3.4 and redis 2.10.5
I'm trying to create a class to put data into instances of that class.

```
class Accounts(list):
    def Account(self):
        return self

    def GetName(self):
        return self.name

    def SetName(self, id):
        self.id=name

    def GetCurrency(self):
        return self.currency

    def SetCurrency(self, nickname):
        self.currency=currency

    def GetBalance(self):
        return self.balance

    def SetBalance(self, id):
        self.balance=balance

    def append(self, object):
        return super().append(object)
```

and somewhere down below I have:

```
acclist = Accounts
for x in accID:
        tv = self.__r.hmget(x, 'name', 'currency', 'balance')
        acclist.append(tv)
```

visual studio doesn't really return any errors. it exits the loop with nil. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You do need to create an *instance* of the class. But why override `append` when just passing this to `super()`? Also, don't use setters and getters, you don't need those when you can use simple attributes instead, as [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: Note that your `SetName` setter gets confused between `name` and `id`.. And `SetCurrency` uses `nickname` as the argument but doesn't use it. Same for `SetBalance` and `id`.

Comment: well, I wasn't overriding append at first, but when it didn't work I tried that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your class the rigth way to create an instance:

```
acclist = Accounts()
```

Comment: thank you! sorry for asking such dumb questions, but I'm completely new to programming, started 2 weeks ago, with no background in something similar!